# How to get border width from a JavaFX scene graph node?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `VBox` and I set its border width to 3 dynamically (without CSS or FXML).

Then I tried to get its border width using

```
myVBox.getBorder().getStrokes().get(0).getLeftStrokeWidth();
```

But it doesn't work! Can anybody help me please?

Comment: total width of the VBox = VBoxWidth+LeftBorderWidth+RightBorderWidth

Comment: Wow, without css or fxml, then how did you manage to change it dynamically?

Comment: Presumably using [`Region.setBorder(border)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setBorder-javafx.scene.layout.Border-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set the border programatically like:

```
VBox vbox = new VBox();
BorderStroke borderStroke = new BorderStroke(Color.RED, BorderStrokeStyle.DASHED, 
    null, new BorderWidths(5));
// Sets all 4 borders
vbox.setBorder(new Border(borderStroke));
```

Then you can get the widths like:

```
double left = vbox.getBorder().getStrokes().get(0).getWidths().getLeft();
System.out.println("Left border width " + left);
```

*Output*

```
Left border width 5.0
```